# cmd command execution using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run three lines of code in cmd window with a batch file.

Commands are

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

What would be the batch script for this operation? I'm using windows.

Thank you.

Comment: what if you copy them into a batch file and run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open notepad. Paste the below into it, select `file`, `save as` and give it a name ending with a `.cmd` extension. Something like `mydnsscript.cmd` then you can simply double click on it to run it.

```
@echo off
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
Pause
```

You can remove `pause` if you want. I simply added it so you can see the batch run and what happened

Comment: cmd window pops up. But nothings happens.

Comment: Worked. After running as Admin

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are mostly just a text file with a `.bat` or `.cmd` file extension and with one cmd.exe instruction per line and you can just do:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

Most batch files start with a command to hide the syntax of each line you are executing:

```
@echo off
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Notepad and copy & paste the following four lines into new file:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe /flushdns
%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe /release
%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe /renew
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> which opens the **Save As** dialog, enter a file name like `ReconfigNetwork.bat` or `ReconfigNetwork.cmd` and make sure option **Encoding** is set to **ANSI** because of batch files must be encoded with 1 byte per character. *(UTF-8 would be also possible, but only without not displayed byte order mark at and requires additional commands in batch file for correct output of non ASCII characters and a font supporting Unicode. So better to use for simple batch files is ANSI encoding, more precisely OEM character encoding.)* Click on button **Save** and exit Notepad.

Double click on the batch file to start `cmd.exe` with implicit using option `/C` to close command process and console window once execution of batch file finished. Or open a command prompt window with implicit using option `/K` to keep command process running and console window open after finishing execution of a command, application or script and run the batch file from within command prompt window by typing its name with full path enclosed in straight double quotes if path or file name contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` for help on Windows command interpreter and `ipconfig /?` for help on this console application.